# Syntax erro:invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting a syntax error in an "if condition". If you guys can help me, I appreciate it. Sorry for my bad English, I'm Brazilian.

I already tried to change the "." to the "," but I didn't get success.

```
elif(salario > 1751.82 and <= 2919.72):

'''print(desconto4)

SyntaxEror: invalid syntax.
```

Comment: Python isn't strictly English. It doesn't know with what it needs to compare `<= 2919.72`.

Answer (score 2):

```
salario > 1751.82 and <= 2919.72
```

This is an invalid `if`/`elif` condition.

Either explicitly write and concatenate 2 conditions:

```
elif salario > 1751.82 and salario <= 2919.72:
```

Or chain the conditions:

```
elif 1751.82 < salario <= 2919.72:
```

Without seeing the other parts of the code, I don't know if there are other errors in your code.